# Difference between two @RequestMapping annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, request-mapping

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following doubt.

In a controller, I have a method annotated in this way:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(params = "register")
    public String createForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
        return "user/register";
    } 

}
```

So this method handle HTTP Request toward the URL **/users?register** where **register** is a parameter (because the entire class handle request toward **/users** resource).

Is it the same thing if, instead using the **params = "register"** I use the following syntaxt:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/users/{register}")
    public String createForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
        return "user/register";
    } 

}
```

I have deleted the mapping at class level and I use **@RequestMapping("/users/{register}")**.

Is it the same meaning of the first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NO, they are completely different constructs:

### Code 1

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(params = "register")
    public String createForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
        return "user/register";
    } 

}
```

In this case, `createForm` method will be called when a HTTP request is made at URL `/users?register`. Quoting from [Spring Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--), it means this method will be called whatever the value of the `register` HTTP parameter; it just has to be present.

> "myParam" style expressions are also supported, with such parameters having to be present in the request (allowed to have any value).

### Code 2

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/users/{register}")
    public String createForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
        return "user/register";
    } 

}
```

In this case, `@RequestMapping` is declaring `register` as a [`PathVariable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html). The method `createForm` will be called if a HTTP request is made at URL `/users/something`, whatever the `something`. And you can actually retrieve this `something` like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{register}")
public String createForm(@PathVariable("register") String register, Model model) {
    // here "register" will have value "something".
    model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
    return "user/register";
}
```

Comment: Perfect explaination, tnx :-)